# Selecionar vários inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-web

Eu tenho a seguinte duvida se é possível melhorar essa seleção:

```
#form-login > input[type="email"], #form-login > input[type="password"] {}
```

Pois se eu tiver vários inputs ficará muito grande..

Comment: Só assim nao funcionaria ? #form-login input{}

Comment: sem colocar o tipo....

Comment: eu gostaria de selecionar por tipo senão altera até o submit

Comment: ah sim, mas isso ai você esta usando no css mesmo ou é na função com jquery?

Comment: No css mesmo obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o not, excluindo o elemento que você não quer que aplique a mesma regra no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
   #form-login input:not([type="submit"]){ background-color:#000;}
```

O seletor not é muito útil para excluir elementos dos seletores quando você não precisa deles. Acho que é o mais adequado no seu caso, em vez de colocar todos que você precisa, apenas retire o que você não quer.
Espero ter ajudado!!